# Find the Difference between two rows and Highlight the difference then loop through all Rows with the Same Code

Tags: excel, vba

I Set up a Macro that Finds the differences between the two rows and then highlights them. I want the macro to Cycle through the next two rows and do the same thing and go on until there are no more rows of data(This Number varies all the time). So the Next selection would be Rows 4:5 and it would Select the differences and highlight them and so on. How is this possible? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you,

```
FindVariance Macro

Rows("2:3").Select
Range("A3").Activate
Selection.ColumnDifferences(ActiveCell).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 15773696
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Range("F16").Select
```

`End Sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
FindVariance Macro

For j=2 to Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row-1
i=j+1
Rows(j & ":" & i).ColumnDifferences(Range("A" & i)).Offset(1,0).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 15773696
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
j=j+1
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: I get the Error:

Run-Time error '1004': Unable to get the ColumnDifferences property of the Range Class. It Highlights Line 3 of the Code: Rows(j & ":" & i).ColumnDifferences(ActiveCell).Select

Comment: There I fixed it, I had missed a part.

Comment: So I was running the code again this morning and I noticed that it Highlights the differences in the first row and not the second row, Ive been trying to figure out how to correct this so that the highlights actually happen on the second row, is it possible?

Comment: so which one do you need to be highlightened? both or just the second row?

Comment: The Second Row, that is the row where I need to verify where the difference occurred, in comparison with the first row.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my sample

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindVariance()
Dim last As Integer, i As Integer, r As Boolean
last = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = 2 To last
    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
        Rows(i & ":" & i + 1).Select
        r = Selection.ColumnDifferences(ActiveCell).Select
        If r = True Then
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 15773696
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next i
Range("F16").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

it's always a good habit to:

- use objects reference and avoid the use of selections

  which can be deceiving and slows down the code
- use full reference for ranges, up to the workbook.

  to avoid point to an unwanted active sheet or workbook!

so here's my code

```
Sub FindVariance()
Dim j As Long
Dim nRows As Long

With ActiveSheet
    nRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 2 To nRows Step 2
        With .Rows(j).Resize(2).ColumnDifferences(.Cells(j + 1, 1)).Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 15773696
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    Next j
End With

End Sub
```

and there's still some job to do in order to catch and properly treat exceptions (uneven number of rows, empty rows...)